# Responsive Javascript events

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, media-queries

I have some doubts about the "best" current method to distinguish Javascript functions in certain screen sizes, because all answers say something different and they don't convince much. As far as I understand, the methods to build "responsive Javascript functions" are:

[matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) function

```
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 500px)').matches) {
```

[width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) function applied to window

```
if ($(window).width() < 500) {
```

And another method that I haven't seen here is:

```
if ($(".sampleClass").css("float") == "none") {
```

that basically check for any CSS propriety that change in a CSS media query:

```
.sampleClass {float:left;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
    .sampleClass {float:none;}
}
```

What's the current "best" method in order to write jQuery functions in certain screen sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the options above are the main ways of accomplishing this. As far as which one to choose:

Using `window.width` is the most common way of having viewport conditional code, as far as I know. However, this has some drawbacks, as is it is not always consistent across browsers. It will typically get the job done, though.

Matchmedia is a more consistent option of you don't need to worry about supporting older browsers, so make sure to check the support for this feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

The final method of comparing classes based on a css media query will also be more consistent and you don't need to worry about browser support. It's a bit lengthier however, so you'll need to take that into consideration.

On the whole though, these will all work. There are just some slight differences to take into account.